# Have a .Net Compact Framework Device losing Windows CE support

Tags: linux, embedded, compact-framework, windows-ce, windows-embedded

Currently the machines run on Windows Embedded, but with support being discontinued in 2021 I need to come up with a long-term solution.

I need a OS solution for a device which has software written in .net compact framework and has the following hardware:

- 256 MB RAM
- 256 MB Storage
- 12.1" SVGA display
- LX 800 processor (500MHz, **which also doesn't support SSE2**)

The new Windows IoT core's minimum requirements is well outside my device's hardware stack.

My concern is that we will need to end up moving to a Linux based OS, and that code in .net compact framework will need to be rewritten because of it.

Is there any solution besides a rewrite or losing support?

Comment: On a Linux platform much of your existing code will probably be able to run on Mono and require little rewrite.

Comment: And what is the problem? Blame the original team for using a environment which had an obviously limited lifetime from the beginning. If you come up with another proprietary framework, you will encounter the same problem is few years. Better do it right once. Don't rely on .net for long-term support devices. Said that, we are not a consulting site.

Comment: @Clifford Is mono still actively being supported in open source?

Comment: @Olaf I'm taking over a project and everyone that made the decision is gone- not that it masters if I chastise them or not he problem remains.

Comment: Since 4.0 Mono has incorporated code released as open source by Microsoft.  Active, yes, but under control of Microsoft, which you may or may not be happy with.  See http://www.mono-project.com/ and also https://www.microsoft.com/net/xamarin, and status/roadmap at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_(software)#Current_status_and_roadmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution as stated in the comments is that there is no solution right now.

Since CF is mostly a subset of .Net (full) the best way is to try and create a normal .Net stack project with the code and fix the CF (mostly mobile) specific library use so it compiles as fully .Net.